# nginx / fpm and PHP_VALUE not working

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php

I am trying to alter some php.ini values for a single site of my web server:

```
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "auto_prepend_file=/var/www/profile/external/header.php \n auto_append_file=/var/www/profile/external/footer.php";
```

but the value is totally ignored by FPM.

I have tried to add the line either on top of the vhost configuration or under the **location ~* .php$ {** directive but none works

Here is my vhost configuration under nginx:

```
server {
  listen          80;
  index           index.php index.html;
  server_name     myvisit;
  root            /var/www/mv/head/myvisit/;
  access_log      /var/log/nginx/myvisit-access.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/myvisit-error.log;

  fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE  "auto_prepend_file=/var/www/profile/external/header.php \n auto_append_file=/var/www/profile/external/footer.php";

  # Use gzip compression
  # gzip_static       on;  # Uncomment if you compiled Nginx using --with-http_gzip_static_module
  gzip                on;
  gzip_disable        "msie6";
  gzip_vary           on;
  gzip_proxied        any;
  gzip_comp_level     5;
  gzip_buffers        16 8k;
  gzip_http_version   1.0;
  gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/$

  # error pages
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /var/www;
  }

  # Deny access to hidden files
  location ~* /\.ht {
    deny            all;
    access_log      off;
    log_not_found   off;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~* /myvisitv3[-_](.*)\.(?:html|php) {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /myvisitv3.php?libAdresse=$1&$args;
  }

  location ~* /favicon.(?:ico|png|bmp|jpg)$ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /web/img/favicon.ico;
  }

  # Pass PHP scripts on to PHP-FPM
  include global/php-fpm.conf;
  location ~* \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    try_files       $uri /index.php;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    php5-fpm-sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE          "auto_prepend_file=/var/www/profile/external/header.php \n auto_append_file=/var/www/profile/external/footer.php";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work in all Linux distributions. For details see the comments on [PHP bug #51595](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51595)

Comment: awwww ! is there a workaround to make it works only for a given vhost ?

Comment: If you have a separate FPM pool for each vhost (and you should for security), you can just put the config into the vhost's FPM pool.

Comment: ok i'll check how to do that :)

Comment: Based on that bug, it may be an escaping issue for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, but only in location context. In server context it works different as one could expect. Discussed on nginx forum: [fastcgi_param in server context does not work](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,8415,8415#msg-8415).